# New line in Outlook task

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have to create Outlook Task from Access. All works fine but I cannot figure out how to create a new line in Body. This is my code:

```vb
Public Function AddOlTask(sSubject As String, sBody As String, _
                    dtDueDate As Date, dtReminderDate As Date)

    Const olTaskItem = 3
    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim OlTask As Object

    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlTask = OlApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

    With OlTask
        .Subject = sSubject
        .DueDate = dtDueDate
        .Status = 3   
        .Importance = 1     
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderTime = dtReminderDate
        .categories = "Business" 
        .Body = sBody
        .Save   
    End With
End Function
```

I tried to use `<br/>`, `vbCrLf`. I tried to assign it similar to Message to property like `.HTMLBody = sBody` (incorrect property). Used `.RTFBody = -1`. Nothing works. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean newline before or after the `sBody`?

Comment: Inside of the body text

Comment: For that you will have to handle it before you pass it to the function `sBody As String` What is the value of `sBody`?

Comment: Something like `AddOlTask "Sid", "Blah Blah" & vbNewLine & "Blah Blha", DateSerial(2020, 3, 12), DateSerial(2020, 3, 13)`

Comment: Sure. I passed there `"SuborderID: " & Me.SuborderID & vbNewLine & "PO Date: " & txtETAonPO` and it did not create a new line. This is t'he result: `SuborderID: 62008PO Date: 3/12/2020`. Similar when using `<br/>`

Comment: Strange. I just tested it. From VBA Outlook and it worked. Tested it from Access as well and it works https://prnt.sc/rfdwgq

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The string has to be written like this:

```vb
"SuborderID: " & Me.SuborderID & vbNewLine & vbCr & "PO Date: " & txtETAonPO
```

It creates this message:

`SuborderID: 62075
PO Date: 3/12/2020`

Comment: If you wanted 2 lines then you could have also used `vbNewLine & vbNewLine`

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. The code above creates only one row.

Comment: `vbNewLine & vbNewLine` will create 2 rows. I have tested it. Anyways seems liek your query is sorted

Comment: Not for me. Maybe because am pasting the string first to Access TextBox (just to let the user edit it) and from there to the function above.